# My dell Inspiron 5520 battery doesn't fully charge

Tags: dell-inspiron

It charges around 76% and doesn't go up. I'm not sure how it happened but I tried every possible thing but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it says **charging** but the percentage doesn't go up it could be a faulty battery. If it says **not charging** then look for Dell power management software, it may have a setting to preserve the long term health of the battery by not fully charging it. Such an option could also be in the BIOS settings.

Comment: Also, you could try fully draining the battery a few times to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you could do is to let it run down completely; and, before doing so, tell your operating system not to shut down until you reach 1% left. Make sure to disable hibernation  and disable screen blanking when running on battery. Then, reboot, and let it sit at the login screen (which means it will shut down faster when it hits that 1%).

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/power-management shows you the Windows 7 power management features. If you use a different OS, search for 'power management' to find how to shut off Hibernation and disable screen blanking on battery.

There's a controller which determines the capacity of the battery, and by a deep cycle, you give it a chance to figure out things are different.

If the full deep discharge-full recharge fails, well, it's new battery time.